# Complications Limits of Powers

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

Sometimes L'Hôpital's rule does not lead to an answer in a finite number of steps unless a transformation of variables is applied.

How can I find the  limit  of the function $f(t)$:

$$\lim_{t\to \infty}f(t)=\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{a e^{-at}+b e^{-bt}-(a+b)e^{-(a+b)t}}{e^{-at}+ e^{-bt}-e^{-(a+b)t}},$$
where $a\geq0$ and $b\geq 0$.

> My attempts
>   $$\lim_{t\to \infty}f(t)=\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{a e^{at}+b
>  e^{bt}-(a+b)}{e^{at}+ e^{bt}-1}$$
>
> if $b=a$.
>
> Either 
>   $$\lim_{t\to \infty}f(t)=\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{a-\frac{2a}{e^{at}+e^{bt}}}{1-\frac{1}{e^{at}+e^{bt}}}=a,$$
>   or
>   $$\lim_{t\to \infty}f(t)=\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{b-\frac{2b}{e^{at}+e^{bt}}}{1-\frac{1}{e^{at}+e^{bt}}}=b.$$

Is this route logical?

Is there another way to prove?

thanks for the help.

Comment: I think the result depend on values  of $a$ and $b$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg since $a,b\geq 0$

Comment: If so we need to know $a>b$, $a<b$ or $a=b$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I can not determine who is older, can I study cases as a whole. Can you clarify cases in answer to me ... Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a>b\geq0$ we obtain:
$$\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{a e^{-at}+b e^{-bt}-(a+b)e^{-(a+b)t}}{e^{-at}+ e^{-bt}-e^{-(a+b)t}}=\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{a e^{(b-a)t}+b-(a+b)e^{-at}}{e^{(b-a)t}+ 1-e^{-at}}=b.$$
If $a=b$ we obtain
$$\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{a e^{-at}+b e^{-bt}-(a+b)e^{-(a+b)t}}{e^{-at}+ e^{-bt}-e^{-(a+b)t}}=\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{2a e^{-at}-2ae^{-2at}}{2e^{-at}-e^{-2at}}=\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{2a -2ae^{-at}}{2-e^{-at}}=a.$$
If $b>a\geq0$ we obtain:
$$\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{a e^{-at}+b e^{-bt}-(a+b)e^{-(a+b)t}}{e^{-at}+ e^{-bt}-e^{-(a+b)t}}=\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{a +b e^{(a-b)t}-(a+b)e^{-bt}}{1+ e^{(a-b)t}-e^{-bt}}=a.$$
The similar things we'll get for $t\rightarrow-\infty$.

Comment: Thanks, Is there a law in general, or is it a logical interpretation?

Comment: @Emad kareem In the general there are very many cases. While the general idea is very easy: If $a>b>0$ then $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{e^{bt}}{e^{at}}=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and clarification.

Comment: @Emad kareem You are welcome!

Comment: if $a=b$  is considered a trivial case.

Answer (score 1):

If $a,b>0$, we factor out $e^{-\min(a,b)t}$ from both denominator and numerator, then we find that $\lim_{t\to\infty} f(t) = \min(a,b)$. If one of them vanishes, w.l.o.g. let $a=0$, then $\lim_{t\to\infty} f(t) = 0$, such that $\lim_{t\to\infty} f(t) = \min(a,b)$ for all $a,b\geq 0$.

Comment: How to apply the function $f(t)$

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. What I'm saying is that you simply need to factor out the exponential of $\exp(-at)$ or $\exp(-bt)$ in $f(t)$, depending on which one is bigger as $t\to \infty$.